# Como alterar uma imagem dinamicamente quando um button é pressionado e guardar o estado dessa imagem

Tags: java, android, button, android-xml

Tenho um problema em que preciso alterar uma imagem de uma `imageView` quando o `Button` for pressionado e quando o mesmo for pressionado novamente altere para a imagem que estava anteriormente. Eu até consegui fazer isso através do `setBackgroundResource`, o problema é quando eu fecho o aplicativo ou saio dessa determinada `Activity` e volto para ela a imagem volta a ser a que estava no  `android:background` desde o início.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Código xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLigarDesligar"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icone_ligar"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgStatus"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icone_vermelho"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

**Código Java**

```
buttonLigarDesligar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int status = 0;

            if (satus == 0){ 
                imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
                status = 1;
            }else{
                imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icone_vermelho);
                status = 0;                   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Você pode guardar essa informação em um banco de dados, ou o ideal no caso seria guardar em um sharedpreferences, se ninguém te responder até amanhã, eu ajudo. Pq agora to fora do pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar SharedPreferences pra guardar a informação do usuário para isso faça o seguinte:

Primeiro dentro da sua Activity declare:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private boolean statusOff;
public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_USER = "user_preferences";
public static final String BUTTON_ON_OFF = "button_on_off";
```

Dentro do método onCreate acrescente:

```
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Caso ainda não tenha sido criada essa preferência o retorno booleano
    //sera true, como destacado embaixo
    statusOff = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(BUTTON_ON_OFF, true);
```

Deixe o evento de clique do seu botão assim:

```
buttonLigarDesligar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                if (statusOff) {
                    imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
                    //agora o valor do sharedpreferences é true, ou seja está ligado.
                    editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_ON_OFF, false);
                } else {
                    //caso o sharedpreference for false, então altera o icone pra vermelho e o valor
                    //booleano passa a ser true.
                    imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icone_vermelho);
                    editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_ON_OFF, true);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
```

Dentro da sua Activity reescreva o método onResume da seguinte maneira:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Para quando a aplicação, for pausada ou parada, o método onResume checará
    //o status do botão que está salvo e caso ele seja "false" então altera
    //o seu background para o ic_on. Caso statusOff seja "true", não tem necessidade
    //de alteração já que você definiu por padrão no xml "icone_vermelho"
    if (!statusOff) {
        imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mt obrigado cara, consegui resolver aqui,não sabia da existência do sharedpreferences kkk, sou novo no android, mas de novo obrigado!